# Import-CSV seems to not import all entries

Tags: powershell, csv, import-csv

I'm currently having issues importing data from a csv file.

The csv file has four columns:

- `appname`,
- `location`,
- `lob`, and
- `os`

In total it has **562** entries.

PowerShell only seems to pick up **274** entries.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

This is my code:

```
Import-CSV applications.csv | ForEach-Object {
    $appname = $_.appname.ToLower()
    $os = $_.os.ToLower()
    $lob = $_.lob.ToLower()
    $location = $_.location.ToLower()

    if ($Applications.Keys -notcontains $appname) {
        $WindowsOS=@{}

        # hash table for Windows XP and Windows 7 applications
        $WindowsOS["windows xp"]=@{}
        $WindowsOS["windows 7"]=@{}
        $Applications[$appname]=$WindowsOS
    } 

    if ($Applications[$appname][$os].Keys -notcontains $lob) {
        $Applications[$appname][$os][$lob]=@()
    }

    if ($Applications[$appname][$os][$lob].Keys -notcontains $location) {
        $Applications[$appname][$os][$lob]+=$location
    }
}

$Applications
```

Comment: Without your input data we could only guess. Do you perhaps have duplicates in your data? Also, how do you count, since you're transforming tabular data into a hierarchical structure?

Comment: (Import-CSV applications.csv).count will tell you how many are being imported

Comment: Import into Excel, see if the count is any different. If counts are the same, your CSV's layout may be broken.